# Why LoopbackJS doesn't set values for emailVerified and verificationToken?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created a custom `Client` model whose base class is a built-in `User` model. I used command-line tool `slc loopback:model` for it. An automatically created config for the model is as follows (`common/models/client.json`):

```
{
  "name": "Client",
  "plural": "Clients",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

So as I understand my custom `Client` model has all the properties and behavior of `User` model.

Now I want to create some `Client` instances and insert them in MongoDB. The docs says about `POST` `/users` HTML requests for creating a new DB entry that Loopback sets some values automatically (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/User+REST+API):

> JSON object (in request body) providing User object properties:
>   username, password, email. **LoopBack sets values for emailVerified and
>   verificationToken**.

But when I run my script, niether `emailVerified`, nor `verificationToken` are set. DB is populated only with the values I pass as a `POST` body. Here is my code:

```
ds.automigrate(collections, function(er) {
    if (er) throw er;
    console.log('Looback tables [' + collections + '] created in ', ds.adapter
        .name);

    server.models.Client.create([{
        username: 'admin',
        password: "admin",
        email: 'admin@gmail.com',
        dtCrt: new Date()
    }, {
        username: 'admin2',
        password: "admin2",
        email: 'admin2@gmail.com',
        dtCrt: new Date()
    }], function(err, newClient) {
        ds.disconnect();
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

And here is a result. No `emailVerified` and `verificationToken` values are set:

```
[ { username: 'admin',
    password: '$2a$10$EdyVnfIATxoOzI6vUeV3POIgKGomY/gtKRXfoWcrTRWZDm0dKl41y',
    email: 'admin@gmail.com',
    dtCrt: Sun Nov 01 2015 20:08:23 GMT+0800,
    id: 563600b85e1c289829390e48 },
  { username: 'admin2',
    password: '$2a$10$ya6yf7iGraPGPvhjtVunZeug1i7/aTF8aSn.mYlqF0zUNVO73DJ8e',
    email: 'admin2@gmail.com',
    dtCrt: Sun Nov 01 2015 20:08:23 GMT+0800,
    id: 563600b85e1c289829390e49 } ]
```

Why? How to make Loopback set those values as its docs says?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation in StrongLoop it requires you to set the User configuration in the server/model-config.json file.

```
"client": {
"dataSource": "db",
"public": true,
"options": {
  "emailVerificationRequired": true
}
```

Creating new Clients should set that to 'false' but with no verificationToken.
There is a full example here : [Loopback user example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management)

But basically, Loopback will set the emailVerified and the verificationToken  settings when:

- you enable the emailVerificationRequired flag
- Add code to register and validate a user.

Comment: But here is the thing. You cannot add code for registering and validating a user if you choose to use a default Loopback's REST API. All that functionality is hardcoded already somewhere under the hood. All you can do is to call `POST` `/Clients` request with new Client's credentials in body. And Loopback has to do everything else - add all requred data in your DB, like `createdAt`, `modifiedAt`, `emailVerified`, `verificationToken`, etc. But it doesn't